# Regular expressions: include text strings in search

Tags: html, regex, replace, notepad++

I extracted a long drop down option list from a html source and hoping to "clean it up" with find & replace function in notepad++ using RegEx, but I struggle with incorporating a known fixed text string in a RegEx.

Here is an extract from html source to give an idea of the recurring pattern I have:

```
"icecream":{"cone":"30p","cup":"16p","double":"10p","waffle":"20p"},
"sorbet":{"cone":"10p","cup":"17p","double":"13p","waffle":"18p"},
```

I am hoping to end up like this (so I can import it into excel):

```
icecream,cone,30p,cup,16p,double,10p,waffle,20p
sorbet,cone,10p,cup,17p,double,13p,waffle,18p
```

This is what I tried:

Find:

```
"([a-z]*)":{"([cone])":"([0-9]*p)","([cup])":"([0-9]*p)","([double])":"([0-9]*p)","([waffle])":"([0-9]*p)"},
```

Replace with: `\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9`

My find step has always returned "0 hits in 0 files" and my guess is those known fixed text ([cone], [cup] etc) are not coded in the correct way. Maybe I am too naive to expect this simple RegEx to work, but having spent the whole day reading tutorials I can only begin understand how people's RegEx works but can't really write a functional one still.

Any help greatly appreciated and thank you very much in advance!

Update:

Got it to work with

"([a-z]*)":{"(cone)":"([0-9]*p)","(cup)":"([0-9]*p)","(double)":"([0-9]*p)","(waffle)":"([0-9]*p)"},

now I have a second problem: some of the prices are "£1" instead of "[0-9]*p", is there a way to include an "OR" command in this scenario? I tried

"([a-z]*)":{"(cone)":"([0-9]*p)|(£1)","(cup)":"([0-9]*p)|(£1)","(double)":"([0-9]*p)|(£1)","(waffle)":"([0-9]*p)|(£1)"},

but it doesn't work. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try putting backslashes in front of your curly braces and quotes. They are special characters.

Comment: The characters [] usually mean a character class in regexes. So you are not looking for the word cone, but just for one character in the set {'c', 'o', 'n', 'e'}.

Comment: Thanks Mad Physicist and Simone-Cu!! I got it to work after adding backslash and replacing the text brackets into (cone), my first RegEx ever!! Now I am just a little away from completing the whole task, I have updated the post to include the new information...

Comment: @user3284375 I think that something like `£?[0-9]*p?` should work well. Another thing, maybe you have decimal. If so include a point into the character class.

Comment: Thanks Simone-Cu! After a good while of trial and error I ended up replacing all ([0-9]*)p into &pound;\1 then clean the whole string with &pound;([0-9|.]*). The problem with £?[0-9|.]*p? is that when I do replace it didn't work, but I guess that is due to the & in &pound; since the source is html. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the char set brackets `[]` around your literal words. Such as `[cone]`.

These are literal words to be matched and not character sets.

Change your regex to this:

```
"([a-z]*)":{"(cone)":"([0-9]*p)","(cup)":"([0-9]*p)","(double)":"([0-9]*p)","(waffle)":"([0-9]*p)"},
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/kO3tU9

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `["{}]|,$`, replace with nothing.
2. Find `:` and replace with `,`.

End result:

```
icecream,cone,30p,cup,16p,double,10p,waffle,20p
sorbet,cone,10p,cup,17p,double,13p,waffle,18p
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have already put together a macro for multiple replacements but it is too slow to run over so many rows (the entire html of drop down list is huge), so although this worked I am hoping for a lighter coding because I am going to do this mass replacement regularly.

Comment: You mean you want to only find/replace once? Unfortunately, you'd have to make a massively slow and carefully exact RegEx to do this.